# Using Arrays.deepToString for different array types

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm fairly new to coding so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I am trying to print a multi-dimensional array using `Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a)`; the only problem is that when I try to do this in Eclipse, it gives me the error: "The method deepToString(Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Board)"

My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gameplay
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Board show = new Board();
        String s = Arrays.deepToString(show.yourBoard(show));
        System.out.print(s);           
    }
}


public class Board
{  
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    private Ship[] ships;


    public Board()
    {
        gameBoard = new char[10][10];
        ships = new Ship[5];

        for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
            for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                gameBoard[r][c] = '~';
    }


    public Board yourBoard(Board input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

The method `yourBoard(Board input)` is supposed to modify `show` in some way but before doing anything, I just want to make sure it returns correctly. Is there anyway I can actually put the `Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a)` method to use with my array so that it actually outputs correctly?

Comment: `Board` _isn't_ an array.  It _contains_ arrays.  (Two different ones.)

Comment: You would need to call `Arrays.deepToString(gameBoard)`. I would recommend you override the `toString` method on `Board`.

Answer (score 0):

First, override `toString()` method on `Board` . `Arrays.deepToString()` receive array, so you should do `Arrays.deepToString(new Board[10])`